# Dell Vostro 1510 trackpad

Tags: dell, trackpad

A week ago I moved totally from Windows 7 to Ubuntu. I've been really happy with the transition bar one annoying glitch.

My trackpad sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. All other hardware including peripherals work flawlessly, including a Logitech ball mouse, Wacom Bamboo pen and touch and wireless Logitech keyboard and mouse combo.

I can't see any pattern to when and why the trackpad works. Occasionally on rebooting, it will work, but then I can reboot 10x in a row and it won't work, then I leave it a day, then reboot and it works flawlessly.

Any ideas on a solution or appropriate method for me to deb it? My knowledge of Ubuntu/Linux is sketchy at best so I could do with a little help :)

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? How about trying the answer posted and report what happens, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

open terminal and execute:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and modify this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.reset"
```

save and close.
after, execute on terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```

reboot machine for apply